How to fix objects appearing?
I’m trying to hide unnecessary objects for optimizations.

But why do objects that are too far away also disappear?

How to fix this?
My file


Your question is not clear. Which objects are "unnecessary"? Perhaps your issue is the Clip End distance on your camera?

@Phrogz There is a file attached at the end of the question.

My apologies, I didn't see that. I would remove my downvote, but cannot do so unless you edit your question.

I mean, without fully having worked through your Geometry Node tree, the one Raycast node immediately caught the eye:

The Raycast Node only calculates casts up to the given Ray Length, which in your case was 100m. Since you delete every point which isn't hit by a ray, every point further away than 100m is deleted. Simply increase the Ray Length slider until everything you want to see in the scene can be hit by a ray shorter than the Ray Length.
